# How to animate background in Android Studio?

Tags: java, android, android-layout

I have in the drawable folder the frames (frame1.png ... frame5.png) and I created inside the drawable folder a bg_animation.xml file.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<animation-list android:id="@+id/backganimate" android:oneshot="false">
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/frame1" android:duration="50" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/frame2" android:duration="50" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/frame3" android:duration="50" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/frame4" android:duration="50" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/frame5" android:duration="50" />
</animation-list>
</selector>
```

I tried to use [this code](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/drawable/AnimationDrawable.html) and it looks like this:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        ImageView img = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.backg);
        img.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.bg_animation);
        AnimationDrawable frameAnimation = (AnimationDrawable) img.getBackground();
        frameAnimation.start();
    }
}
```

There is an ImageView in the XML, it looks like this:

```
    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/backg" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

When I launch the app in my phone (4.4.2), it crashes with this error:

> java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity
>   ComponentInfo{hu.media.smk.test/hu.media.smk.test.MainActivity}:
>   java.lang.ClassCastException:
>   android.graphics.drawable.StateListDrawable cannot be cast to
>   android.graphics.drawable.AnimationDrawable

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just remove the selector

Use this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<animation-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/backganimate" android:oneshot="false">
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/frame1" android:duration="50" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/frame2" android:duration="50" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/frame3" android:duration="50" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/frame4" android:duration="50" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/frame5" android:duration="50" />
</animation-list>
```

instead of

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<animation-list android:id="@+id/backganimate" android:oneshot="false">
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/frame1" android:duration="50" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/frame2" android:duration="50" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/frame3" android:duration="50" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/frame4" android:duration="50" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/frame5" android:duration="50" />
</animation-list>
</selector>
```